# Jsoup isn't parsing all the threads on reddit (only first 7)

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to parse https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapcsales/top/

```
Url url = new Url(textFilePath.getFilereader());
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get();
Elements threadTitle = doc.select("h3._eYtD2XCVieq6emjKBH3m");
```

Comment: It would go much easier for you to use Reddit API, rather than try to scrape the rendered pages. Rendered pages are full of magic. I believe [JRAW](https://github.com/mattbdean/JRAW) is still current.

Comment: Quite possibly it's something like only the first 7 threads show up within the height of the "window" that Jsoup "renders", and more would appear on scroll.